# Call endpoint from Kubernetes Cron Job

Tags: cron, kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a webapp running in a Docker-container in a Kubernetes cluster. The app has an endpoint I want to be called periodically. The app runs at multiple nodes/pods, and it is important that only one node performs the task initiated by the endpoint. I have looked at Kubernetes Cron Jobs, but have not found any documentation on calling endpoints from a Kubernetes Cron Job. Does anybody have any proposal for a solution of this problem? How do you handle scheduling in a cluster where it is crucial that only one node performs the task?

Comment: Do you mean only 1 node concurrently? Only 1 node ever? Does the 1 node need to be the node calling the endpoint or is the 1 node the endpoint being called? Is it important to only call 1 Pod and it doesn't matter what node it is on, or is it any Pod on one node?

Comment: It is important to only call 1 pod each day at a certain time and it doesn't matter what node it is on. The 1 pod is the endpoint beeing called.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`CronJob`s are a good choice. Here's a quick layout that runs 3 nginx pods accepting all traffic. Every minute, a `Job` curls 1 of the 3 pods (always the same pod).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: main
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: singleton
  labels:
    app: nginx
    special: singleton
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      special: singleton
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        special: singleton
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: allpods
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: singleton
spec:
  selector:
    special: singleton
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

---

apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: callout
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: callout
            image: buildpack-deps:curl
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - curl http://singleton
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: may i ask why do u need the second service? hasn't the first service already covered what the second service's doing? (forgive me if that's a stupid question. i'm new to kubernetes)

Comment: The `allpods` service targets `Pods` from both services by using the `app: nginx` label that both `Deployments` include. The `singleton` `Service` only targets the `singleton` `Deployment`. The `allpods` `Service` would be the one most users would target. The `singleton` `Service` is specifically the use case of `it is important that only one node performs the task` from the original question. You can see the `Cronjob` targets `http://singleton` so that the same single `Pod` handles that task.

Comment: @coreypobrien is it necessary to have two services to achieve this? For instance: If you have 3 pods and one service targeting the 3 of them, if a request is sent to the service, the service will redirect it to only one of the pods, as far as I understand